# Count multiple values sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to Oracle and im having some trouble with counting multiple values

Count the number of copies of each book (Copy_num), how many book copies of each book are checked out (Date_out), how many are on hold(Held_for_CID), and how many are available for checkout.

Can this be done by one query? Can't figure out how to count more than one variable at a time.

```
create table BOOK_COPY
(Copy_Num number(5),
Bookid  number(5),
out_to_CID number(6),
Date_Out date,
Date_Due date,
Held_Until date,
held_for_CID number(6),
CONSTRAINT PKCOPY PRIMARY KEY (Copy_Num,Bookid),
CONSTRAINT FKCID FOREIGN KEY (out_to_CID) references CUSTOMER,
CONSTRAINT FKHeld FOREIGN KEY (held_for_CID) references CUSTOMER,
CONSTRAINT FKBookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK);
```

Comment: the referenced tables (`customer`,`book`) must be specified on which column (primary key) they are referenced. I'm talking only about the syntax

Comment: So, MySQL, Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: SQL*Plus is an Oracle thing. So I'm removing the other tags.

Comment: Like this: 
CONSTRAINT FKHeld FOREIGN KEY (held_for_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID) and 
CONSTRAINT FKBookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK (Bookid));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want something like

```
SELECT bookID,
       COUNT( copyNum ) number_of_copies,
       SUM( CASE WHEN date_out IS NOT NULL
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END ) number_copies_out,
       SUM( CASE WHEN held_for_CID IS NOT NULL
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END ) number_copies_reserved
  FROM book_copy
 GROUP BY bookID
```

Once you `GROUP BY bookID`, you can include as many aggregate functions (`SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.) as you'd like.  To count the number of copies out and reserved, I'm using a `CASE` statement that returns 1 if the field in question is `NOT NULL` and then a `SUM` to total up all the 1's.